# Complex TextView alignment and wrapping

Tags: android-layout, user-interface, textview, android-linearlayout, androidx

I don't know how to explain my problem but below on image is what I need to do:
[image]

On image I have 4 textview in a linear layout.

I  want a long text to be wrapped and to go to the new line at bottom to another textView.

how could I have 4 textView like on that image ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use flexlayout

Comment: I'm googling now to know what is flexlayout, how it works and how to use it. If you could make a little more effort for me, I would be happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Add dependency to your gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:2.0.1'
}
```

and add this to your xml file:

```
<com.google.android.flexbox.FlexboxLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  app:alignContent="flex_start"
  app:alignItems="flex_start"
  app:flexWrap="wrap"
  app:showDivider="beginning|middle"
  app:dividerDrawable="@drawable/divider" >

  <TextView
      style="@style/FlexItem"
      android:layout_width="220dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="1" />
  <TextView
      style="@style/FlexItem"
      android:layout_width="120dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="2" />
  <TextView
      style="@style/FlexItem"
      android:layout_width="160dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="3" />
  <TextView
      style="@style/FlexItem"
      android:layout_width="80dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="4" />
  <TextView
      style="@style/FlexItem"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:text="5" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I dont think if that library could make textView like the `TextView 2` on my image. I'm looking for the way to make TextView like the `TextView 2` on my image. Did not you do anything like that ?

Comment: you can also use a single textview and use spannable for text boldness or text color

Answer (score 0):

After many days of search; I did not find anything.
It is not possible to align TextViews like that.

The solutions is using the [SpannableString.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString)